# how to add different classes to primary links in drupal6?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, content-management-system

I am making custom theme in  drupal6. I want to assign different css classes to  different menu. how can i do this. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to use the [Menu Attributes module](http://drupal.org/project/menu_attributes).

From the module's project page:

> You should use this module when
>
> - You want to "nofollow" certain menu items to sculpt the flow of PageRank through your site
> - You want to give a menu item an ID so you can easily select it using jQuery
> - You want to add additional classes or styles to a menu item
>
> The module currently allows you to set the following attributes for each menu item:
>
> - Id
> - Name
> - Target
> - Rel
> - Class Style
> - Accesskey